# Extract column info based on index of another Data frame for time based Data frames - Avoid Iterating

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 DataFrames indexed by Time.

```
import datetime as dt
import pandas as pd

rng1 = pd.date_range("11:00:00","11:00:30",freq="500ms")
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A':range(1,62), 'B':range(1000,62000,1000)},index = rng)

rng2 = pd.date_range("11:00:03","11:01:03",freq="700ms")
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Z':range(10,880,10)},index = rng2)
```

I am trying to assign 'C' in df1 the last element of 'Z' in df2 closest to time index of df1. The following code seems to work now (returns a list).

```
df1['C'] = None
for tidx,a,b,c in df1.itertuples():
    df1['C'].loc[tidx] = df2[:tidx].tail(1).Z.values
    #df1['C'].loc[tidx] = df2[:tidx].Z -->Was trying this which didn't work

df1
```

Is it possible to avoid iterating.

Comment: This is a bit odd, your second df has a different interval for the it's index so your call to `loc` will fail because that label doesn't exist, can you explain better what you require, are you trying to assign to 'C' the value of z for the row in df2 where it's index is up to and including the corresponding index value in df1? I can't see how you can avoid iterating here as you have to perform some index operation for each value in df1 index

Comment: @EdChum I have updated the query. Now with the modified code, I am able to retrieve the values of Z. But they are returned as list (since Series.values() return list),it would have easier to have them returned as string. I have modified the question to see if it is possible to avoid iterating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TIL: Pandas Index instances have map method attributes.

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.map.html

```
def fn(df):
    def inner(dt):
        return df.ix[abs(df.index - dt).argmin(), 'Z']
    return inner

df1['C'] = df1.index.map(fn(df2))
```